# How to Load java frame jar file in HTML

Tags: java, html

I am working with java project and to post my java frame in website. I created a jar file of that Java frame but not able to access to html web page. Help me out!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Project Idea</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><object type="application/x-java-applet" width="300" height="300"> <param name="code" value="MyPage.class" /> <param name="archive" value="Preliminary_app.jar" /> <param name="mayscript" value="true" /> Java failed to load </object></p>  
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried this code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Project Idea</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <applet code="MyPage.class" archive="Preliminary_app.jar" width=800 height=840></applet>
    </body>
</html>
```

Both are not working help me out to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Java Applets are **deprecated** and **not supported** by any major browser anymore.

You can read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/web-browsers-that-support-java-applets-and-how-to-enable-them/) how to enable it in IE.

Comment: Even in IE it is not executing after enabling it. Is there any other option to execute this code or there is any alternatives to be made.

Comment: @NandloSenju Yes - you would need to download very old version of some browser which supports Java Applets.